# AWS Real time data fetching

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have an application which needs to read data from AWS dynamodb table every 5 seconds.
Currently I fetch the data using lambda, and then getting the data from dynamodb back to the user.

The problem with querying the table every 5 seconds is that it can have performance affect and moreover there is a pricing issue. (Most of the time the data might not even be changed at all but when it is changed I want to be notified it immediately).

An important clarification is that my app sits outsite of AWS, and only access the AWS dynamodb to get data (using simple http request built with c#).

Is there any way I can get a notification to my app when a new data is inserted into dynamodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add something on top of @john-rotenstein answer:

Once you have properly configured a Lambda function to be triggered by an event from a DynamoDB Stream, you could have your Lambda function notify your Web Application via an HTTP Request.

Another option is to use Lambda to put this notification in a Queue you may be using outside AWS and then have your C# code be a consumer of this Queue. There are several possibilities to notify your application, you just need to see which one is the best / most cost effective for your current scenario.

Comment: Can you just elaborate a little bit about how lambda function can notify my web application via an HTTP request? (This is exactly what I want to achieve)

Comment: Yes. Once your Lambda is running, you can just use a module like https://www.npmjs.com/package/request to make an HTTP call to your existing application. All you really need to do is configure your Lambda to be triggered by DynamoDB Streams (which is quite straightforward to be honest)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks alot!

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

A data update in DynamoDB can trigger a DynamoDB Stream, which can trigger an AWS Lambda function.

The Lambda function could notify your application in some way.

See: [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand. I saw this but I need the result back to my application which sits outside AWS. How this helps me to avoid pooling?

Comment: How do you want your application to receive a notification?

Comment: Currently I fetch the information from the dynamodb table using HTTP request but if I do it every 5 seconds it might be expensive and most of the time I won't get any data at all. I would like to receive a notification to one of my c# classes, and when I get a notification, only then I will make the HTTP request.

Comment: Maybe this one can be a good idea: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/EnableLongPolling.html - What are your thougts? - After reading more about this one, it's not good enough because the maximum time to wait for event is 15 mintues while I want to wait forever.

Comment: John, thank you very much for the response, I will learn how to use DynamoDB streams to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Streams is the right answer in terms of engineering, but just to say your concern about the polling option being expensive is unfounded. Therefore if you have a working solution I would be tempted to leave it.

If you queried a table every 5 seconds, it would cost you $0.25 every 2 months.

This assumes your table has on-demand pricing, and the query returns less than 4KB of data.

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: Thank you Stu, Actually this points troubled me because there is no single app who query the data (there might be more than 100). Therefore this can get quite expensive, and on large scale can get even very expensive. But for starting, I understand your points and it makes me feel very comfortable to go with this solution. Thank you!